# How do I obtain the taylor expansion of the matrix logarithm sum

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the series expansion of the logarithm of the sum of two square matrices $A$ and $B$,

$\log(A + \epsilon B)$

near $\epsilon=0$?

Is there something similar to Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula?

(**edit: $A$ is invertible, and $A$ and $B$ do not commute**)

Answer (score 0):

I would try expanding the logarithm function in the Taylor series, then simplify every term and collect the powers of $\epsilon$:

$$
\log(A + \epsilon B) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{(A + \epsilon B - I)^m}{i}
$$

Every term of the sum would contribute a finite number of summands to every power of $\epsilon$. The problem is that, for noncommuting $A$ and $B$ this may become complicated.